# Monotonicity property almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm studying for a qualifying exam and having difficulty showing the following:

Let $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ be a real-valued locally integrable function. Suppose that for each positive integer, $f(x+1/n)\geq f(x)$ for almost every $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
Show that for each real number $a\geq 0$, $f(x+a)\geq f(x)$ for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

How to approach this type of problem?

Comment: I can't say anything about "this type of problem". But for this problem I'd first show it was true for rational $a$. Then given an irrational $a>0$ I'd choose rational $a_n$ converging to $a$, recall or prove that $\int|f(x+a_n)-f(x+a)|\,dx\to0$, and use the fact that convergence in norm implies almost everywhere convergence of a subsequence...

Comment: Thanks I think I know how to do this.